# How change one instance firefox icon?

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, taskbar, icons

I have two instances of firefox:

- /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
- ~/Documents/firefox

I would change icon firefox in ~/Documents/firefox.
I think that creating .desktop shortcut solve problem. But when program show in taskbar, it have default icon.

Do you have any ideas?

[image: image explanation]

Thank you for your attention :P

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 profiles for Firefox & want 2 different icons to show in the launcher/taskbar.
I use the below approach, similar steps may help solve your issue.

For me Firefox icons are loaded from [InstallDir]/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default.

So I created a soft link for the "default" which points to the folder from where firefox picks the icons. e.g. default -> default_syn (load icons for profile syn,from default_syn ) & default -> default_fox (load icons from default_fox for default profile) . Make sure the filename in both the folders have exactly the same names.

Before launching the firefox , I will update the soft link to point to the appropriate icons folder.

Below is an alias for profile_1 , it will remove existing link, create a new link to the icons folder & launch firefox.

```
alias syn='rm -rf ~/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default  && ln -s  ~/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default_syn ~/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default && ~/firefox/firefox &'
```

Below Firefox launched from script.

```
ln -s  ~/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default_fox ~/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default
~/firefox/firefox --profile ~/1.mozilla/firefox/firefoxProfile__  &
```

[From My setup, running 2 firefox binaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG6Ix.png)

I guess if you 2 installed version ,fixing the icons from [InstallDir]/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default  should solve your issue.